# Keep only the first and the centre part of a string between "_"

Tags: r, regex

I have a file with hundreds of lines like:

```
>hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_006820_utr3_8_0_chr1_78641810_f
```

For only those lines that have the ">" symbol I want to extract the ">" and the "NM_...". In the example above I want to get:

```
>NM_006820
```

I'm not sure if this is important but there is also the possibility that some lines share the output (">NM_006820") more than once.

Tried with `gsub()` but got completely lost.

Comment: For the lines having more than one `NM_006820` how do you want the output

Comment: I want exactly the same output! My only concern was that somehow the function will remove the duplicated lines.

Comment: Looks like you just need `str_extract_all(x, ">NM_\\d+")`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the `>` at the start (`^`) of the string, capture as a group (`(..)`), followed by characters (`.*`) followed by `_` and then capture the two upper case letters followed by `_` and one or more numbers (`\\d+`).  In the replacement, we use the backreference of the captured groups

```
sub("^(>).*_([A-Z]{2}_\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", str1)
#[1] ">NM_006820"                           ">NM_006820"
#[3] "Some text without > at the beginning"
```

If we need to have all the instance of `NM_\\d+`, then

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- sapply(str_extract_all(str1, "^>|[A-Z]{2}_\\d+"), function(x) 
                         toString(paste0(x[1], x[-1]) ))

i1 <- !grepl("^>", v1)
v1[i1] <- str1[i1]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c(">hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_006820_utr3_8_0_chr1_78641810_f", 
     ">hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_006820_utr3_NM_006820_8_0_chr1_78641810_f",
   "Some text without > at the beginning")
```

Comment: Hi! The solution worked nice but in some other files, the lines that do not have ">" would be like: "ACGATCGA...". Do you think the second capture will be messy in this kind of files?

Comment: @JoanGibertFernandez  If you don't have the `>`, what should be the expected output.  In my second solution, I used the original string to remain as such

Comment: If there is no > the lines should remain untouched. With the example:

>hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_006820_utr3_8_0_chr1_78641810_f
GATAAGTTGCCTTGATTCTGACATTTGGCCCAGCCTGTACTGGTGTGCCGCAATGAGAGTCAATCTCTATTGACAGCCTG...

Should get:

>NM_006820
GATAAGTTGCCTTGATTCTGACATTTGGCCCAGCCTGTACTGGTGTGCCGCAATGAGAGTCAATCTCTATTGACAGCCTG...

Comment: Hi @akrun, when I performed the `sapply` function, in the v1 I got only the NM and I don't know why but they are kept in two like:

`NM_006820NM_144624, NM_006820NM_001184763, NM_006820NM_175866...`

Comment: @JoanGibertFernandez  It should have `, ` as I used `toString` and it is found to be working with the example you showed in the post